# Python Regex - check to make sure something has a space, but not two

Tags: python, regex

What I am trying to do is make sure that there is a space after something, as well as before the next thing, but there can also be words in-between

eg `hello <word> goodbye` or `hello goodbye`

when I try to check for this in regex `hello\s+.*\s+goodbye`

The problem with this code is that if there is not a word in the middle of hello and goodbye, then it will look for two spaces, and then count it as not seeing the correct thing.

Basically, I am trying to make sure that there is a space, and only one space, if there is or is not a word between hello and goodbye.

EDIT: still getting used to this strict definition of regex. the problem is also that there is the possibility of having something like `helloabcdef <word> goodbye` or `hello <word> aksdjhsdflkhgoodbye` which should show as false

Comment: `.*` doesn't look like "words" to me. Do you really mean words?

Comment: If what you try to do is just look for superfluous spaces in a string just negate the pattern you have in mind `not re.search(r' {2,}', string)`. But in that case `'  ' not in string` suffices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to match only one space, then why are you using `\s+` with quantifier? That will match 1 or more spaces. You should use just `\s`.

Now as for your issue, you can use this regex for matching those strings:

```
hello\s(\S+\s)?goodbye
```

Note the use of `\S+`. That makes sure that the capture group will match only when there is at least one non-whitespace character between the 2 spaces. Using `.` won't work, as it matches any character, and hence will match a space also. And, if you use `\S*` instead, then it will also match the following string: `hello\s\sgoodbye`. Note there are 2 spaces there.

Comment: "at least one character..." including space. So it matches with 4 or more spaces because `.` matches any character.

Comment: @digenishjkl Ooops, a mistake. Fixed it. Thanks :)

Comment: Why `[^\s]`? There is `\S` available for this case.